# Error mb_regex_encoding al actualizar a prestashop 8.0.4

Tags: php, prestashop, php8

Creo este hilo a la falta de documentación encontrada sobre este problema. He actualizado la versión de PHP a la 8.1 y actualizado la tienda de prestashop a la 8.0.4. Parecía que todo bien, pero a la hora de acceder al panel de pedidos me muestra el siguiente error:

Attempted to call function "mb_regex_encoding" from the global namespace.

Para poder funcionar con la tienda tuve que deshabilitar el módulo ps_mbo. He buscado documentación sobre ese error pero se me indica que es por el módulo de mbstring que no está habilitado.

En mi fichero de php.ini sí que está habilitada la extensión:

extension=mbstring

pero al comprobar si está habilitada me indica que no. No sé si será por tener dos carpetas con los .so en /usr/lib/php/ ya que tengo:

/usr/lib/php/20220829 donde está mbstring.so

y /usr/lib/php/20210902 donde están el resto de .so que hay en mi php.ini

Ya probé a poner extension_dir a la ruta de mbstring pero sigue indicando que no está habilitado dicho módulo.

Me he quedado sin opciones, así que si alguien ya le ha pasado y lo ha solucionado agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Si, también probé y el error que me indica es: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: ¿Que distro de Linux usas? ¿Como instalaste la versión 8.1 de PHP? Seguramente te falto instalar `php8.1-mbstring`

Comment: @Marcos pues si, era eso, me faltaba instalar esa librería para la versión concreta de php. Muchísimas gracias!